# Markov Chain Basic Probability Question

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains, actuarial-science

Trying to revise for my upcoming exams however our university doesn't give any solutions so it makes revision rather difficult.

I've got this question: https://gyazo.com/835a68414bc7b52ded90501b86b9442b

I've attempted part a but I may have gone about it wrong, Given X_0 = G

We are looking for P_gw * P_wr

My only confusion is whether I need to work out the matrix P^2?

I have done that and therefore my answer would be 0.34 * 0.17 = 0.0578

Any guidance on part b would be extremely helpful as well!

I apologise that my matrix isn't formatted but I am unsure how to input my 4x4 matrx into LaTeX, if anyone would be able to do it for me that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For  part (a) you have overcomplicated what is being asked. $p_{gw} \times p_{wr} = 0.4 \times 0.1$.  For part (b) you have a geometric distribution

Comment: [Here is a guide on formatting matrices.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5023) You will find tutorials on other typesetting commands on that page as well. Also if you want to improve the question, please [edit it](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3991678/edit) by clicking the edit button under the question body, instead of deleting and reposting.

Comment: @Henry Thank you very much! So would my answer for part b just become, 1/p where p = 0.6, therefore the expected number of cars (Including the one we started with) is 2.67?

Comment: Not quite: $p={1-p_{rr}}=0.4$ so $\frac1p=2.5$ (and then you count the start but not the end, so no change)